# Iterate a spark pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pipeline

Currently I'm working on a Sentiment analysis project using Spark. I'm trying to implement a pipe line like this:

**Raw text**---(Tokenized)-->**Tokenized Words**---(join with Sentiment Dictionary)--->**Words with Sentiment value**---(distribute words to sentence again)--->**Sentence with Sentiment value**---(average sentiment value of words from sentence it appeared in)--->**new Sentiment Dictionary**

Now i want to repeat this process until the different between 2 new Sentiment Dictionary in 2 consecutive iterations are bellow a defined value. However, I'm not sure how do I do this, I wrote a custom transformer for this pipeline (since most of my transformer are not available in ml library). On the step of iteration, I'm not sure what's the best way to do this. Should I just put a while loop there and repeat everything, or there is a better mechanism?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is no native support for iteration in Spark but nothing prevents you to apply the same function over and over to the same RDD.

For example if you call a .map() in a for loop over the same RDD, it will be applied multiple times. You can also insert conditions and so on. I don't know how it works with Spark Pipelines because I never worked with that.

Comment: I tried it and for some reason after the first two iteration it slow like hell. I still can't figure out why.